# Focus an input when it is not filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How can I focus an input when one of them is not filled. 
Right now I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/jalxob/ahQLC

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
if ($.trim($("#email").val()) === "" || $.trim($("#user_name").val()) === "") {
    $( ".email1" ).addClass( "focusred" );
    $( ".name1" ).addClass( "focusred" );
    return false;
}  });
```

It shows the red focus but in both inputs although one of them is filled.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#form').submit(function () {
    var result = true,
        focus_class = "focusred",
        elements = $("input#user_name,input#email");

    elements.each(function (index, element) {
        var element = $(element);
        if ($.trim(element.val()) === "") {
            element.addClass(focus_class);
            result = false;
        } else {
            element.removeClass(focus_class);
        }
    })
    return result;
});
```

Update, better answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/SobiborTreblinka/6UgxJ/3/

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    if ($.trim($("#email").val()) === "") {
        $( "#email" ).focus();
        return false;
    }
    if ($.trim($("#user_name").val()) === "") {
        $( "#user_name" ).focus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v64C8/)

Comment: Yeah, this should do it.

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't do what I am looking for. If non of these inputs are filled, only one is focused :(

Comment: @user2989327 at one time only one can be focused... but you can add a class to highlight the element

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
if ($.trim($("#email").val()) === "")
{
    $( ".email1" ).addClass( "focusred" ).focus();
}
if ($.trim($("#user_name").val()) === "")
{
     $( ".name1" ).addClass( "focusred" ).focus();
}
    return false;
```

});

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahQLC/7/)